# SQL optimisation - Word count in string - Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization, parallel-processing

I am trying to update a large table (about 1M rows) with the count of words in a field on Postgresql.
This query works, and sets the `token_count` field counting the words (tokens) in `longtext` in table `my_table`:

```
UPDATE my_table mt SET token_count = 
    (select count(token) from 
      (select unnest(regexp_matches(t.longtext, E'\\w+','g')) as token
      from my_table as t where mt.myid = t.myid)
    as tokens);
```

`myid` is the primary key of the table.
`\\w+` is necessary because I want to count words, ignoring special characters.
For example, `A test . ; )` would return 5 with space-based count, while 2 is the right value.
The issue is that it's horribly slow, and 2 days are not enough to complete it on 1M rows.
What would you do to optimised it? Are there ways to avoid the join?

How can I split the batch into blocks, using for example `limit` and `offset`?

Thanks for any tips,

Mulone

**UPDATE:** I measured the performance of the array_split, and the update is gonna be slow anyway. So maybe a solution would consist of parallelising it. If I run different queries from `psql`, only one query works and the others wait for it to finish. How can I parallelise an update?

Comment: [For a new method that uses FTS, see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42713013/124486)

Answer (score 13):

Have you tried using `array_length`?

```
UPDATE my_table mt
SET token_count = array_length(regexp_split_to_array(trim(longtext), E'\\W+','g'), 1)
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html

```
# select array_length(regexp_split_to_array(trim(' some long text  '), E'\\W+'), 1);
 array_length 
--------------
            3
(1 row)
```

Comment: Maybe `string_to_array` will be even better? E.g. `select array_length(string_to_array('abc abc abc',' '),1)`

Comment: `select( array_length(regexp_matches('this is a test', E'\\w+','g'), 1));` return a table, not a single count :-/

Comment: An issue with `string_to_array` is that only considers spaces, while my solution count actual words, and not special chars.

Comment: the proposed solution sets everything to `1`.

Comment: Add one `count()` as described [here](http://stormbyte.blogspot.cz/2012/05/count-regexp-matches-on-table-sorting.html)

Comment: @Mulone: I've updated the query. Sorry about the error in the initial one. :-) The new one still admittedly contains issues, but it should put you on the right track.

Comment: This gory expression works too: `select array_length(array(select regexp_matches(' some long text ', E'\\w+', 'g')::text),1);`

Comment: Note that this also counts the no-break space, the zero-width joiner, and possibly other characters as spaces. If your text contains emojis, this could be problematic because some multi-character emojis have ZWJs in them. Clodoaldo Neto's answer below doesn't count zero-width joiners (and IDK about the others).

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE my_table
SET token_count = array_length(regexp_split_to_array(longtext, E'\\s+'), 1)
```

Or your original query without a correlation

```
UPDATE my_table
SET token_count = (
    select count(*)
    from (select unnest(regexp_matches(longtext, E'\\w+','g'))) s
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

## Using [`tsvector` and `ts_stat`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-textsearch.html)

> get statistics of a tsvector column

```
SELECT *
FROM ts_stat($$
  SELECT to_tsvector(t.longtext)
  FROM my_table AS t
$$);
```

No sample data to try it but it should work.

### Sample Data

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE my_table
AS 
  SELECT $$A paragraph (from the Ancient Greek παράγραφος paragraphos, "to write beside" or "written beside") is a self-contained unit of a discourse in writing dealing with a particular point or idea. A paragraph consists of one or more sentences.$$::text AS longtext;

SELECT *
FROM ts_stat($$
  SELECT to_tsvector(t.longtext)
  FROM my_table AS t
$$);

     word     | ndoc | nentry 
--------------+------+--------
 παράγραφος   |    1 |      1
 written      |    1 |      1
 write        |    1 |      2
 unit         |    1 |      1
 sentenc      |    1 |      1
 self-contain |    1 |      1
 self         |    1 |      1
 point        |    1 |      1
 particular   |    1 |      1
 paragrapho   |    1 |      1
 paragraph    |    1 |      2
 one          |    1 |      1
 idea         |    1 |      1
 greek        |    1 |      1
 discours     |    1 |      1
 deal         |    1 |      1
 contain      |    1 |      1
 consist      |    1 |      1
 besid        |    1 |      2
 ancient      |    1 |      1
(20 rows)
```

Comment: Note that this will completely ignore stop words.

Answer (score -2):

1. Make sure `myid` is indexed, being the first field in the index.
2. Consider doing this outside DB in the first place. Hard to say without benchmarking, but the counting may be more costly than select+update; so may be worth it.

   - use COPY command (BCP equivalent for Postgres) to copy out the table data efficiently in bulk to a file
   - Run a simple Perl script to count. 1 million rows should take couple of minutes to 1 hour for Perl, depending on how slow your IO is.
   - use COPY to copy the table back into DB (possibly into a temp table, then update from that temp table; or better yet truncate the main table and COPY straight into it if you can afford the downtime).
3. For both your approach, AND the last step of my approach #2, update the token_count in batches of 5000 rows (e.g. set rowcount to 5000, and loop the updates adding `where token_count IS NULL` to the query

Comment: how can I limit the query to N rows?

Comment: Having Perl as one of the built in languages the idea of transferring records in/out the DB seams weird. Why not use Perl (or any other built in language) inside a DB?

Comment: BTW The idea of table outside a DB to update one of the fields is really bad.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko - That depends on their setup. I'm used to a central DB serving 100s of apps and 1000s of users - offloading a task like this to a server separate from DB is generally a good idea.