# How to extract all rows of a single word

Tags: postgresql

I use PostgreSQL 13 on windows 10. I have a table with text-type columns. I'm looking for a query to find all the rows that contain just a single word is not accurate in a specific column.

Any ideas?

My table in database the form of, I try to extract all the rows with a single word.

[image]

output:

```
alvi
alexander
elmar
mahmoud
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL optimisation - Word count in string - Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197929/sql-optimisation-word-count-in-string-postgresql) // or [this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/239878) ?

Comment: no, that is not the context of my question.

Comment: Well, welcome to StackOverflow. Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). StackOverflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation. We expect you to work through the available tutorials. Also, please do not post images of code or data, and please indicate what you have already tried and why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this :

```
SELECT Name
  FROM your_table
 WHERE Name ~ '^\w+$'
```

see the power of the regular expressions in the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)

Comment: @Ziko - thank you to close the question by accepting the answer.